# SFMC Journey Builder - Decision split filter criteria logic?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm quite new to SFMC (1 year experience) and trying to understand what is expected behavior in the filter criteria in decision splits. Because it does not behave the way I think it should and maybe I'm missing an important aspect here.

The journey is quite simple. I use Add to Campaign as my entry source. Then I wait for 20 minutes for the sync to complete and then I have my decision split where I check if a contact/lead has given a consent for receiving newsletters.

[image]

I want both Contacts and Leads to be considered here. So the first AND pair is Contacts > Marketing Consents, whereas the second AND is Leads > Marketing Consents, both combined in an OR statement.

However, when running the journey, only the first AND statement was considered. All my contacts and my leads were evaluated against that first AND statement, while the second AND statement was completely ignored. Resulting in all my leads to go down the Remainder path.

Is this expected behavior that I was not aware of? And what would then be the solution?

Comment: Can you expand on "Add to Campaign" entry source.  Do you mean Salesforce Data Entry Event?  If so are you using the Salesforce Data option not the Campaign option?  And selecting both Contacts/Leads under campaignmember in the object selection?

Comment: @TimZ Yes, I mean Salesforce Data Entry. I'm using the Campaign option. And I'm adding both (Common data: Contact ID/Lead ID)

Comment: Can you try using the Salesforce Data Entry option, but select the Salesforce Data option, not campaign.  You select your object - "campaignmember", Contact and leads and follow the UI from there.  We've not found the campaign option reliable.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try.
But to come back to my original question: my set-up was correct, wasn't it? It should have considered both?

Comment: I replicated your use case using the SF Data vs Campaign path and it worked.  If helpful I can share screen captures of the setup for you to compare.

Comment: Yes, sure, that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a walk through of how to create a SF Data entry event.  I'll write up a post specific to your use case this weekend. https://handsonsfmc.com/how-to-create-a-salesforce-data-entry-event/

Comment: Thanks! Awesome